# Framer Motion pathLength property not working

Tags: reactjs, svg, framer-motion

I ran into a weird issue with Framer Motion today.

For some reason, this snippet (copied and pasted from their website) doesn't work, only the opacity is animated

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const icon = {
    hidden: {
        pathLength: 0,
        fill: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)"
    },
    visible: {
        pathLength: 1,
        fill: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
        transition: { duration: 4 }
    }
};

const SVGComponent = props => {
    return (
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <motion.path
                d="M0 100V0l50 50 50-50v100L75 75l-25 25-25-25z"
                variants={icon}
                initial="hidden"
                animate="visible"
            />
        </svg>
    );
};

export default SVGComponent;
```

Hope you guys will be able to help out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the line is not appearing because you are missing the stroke colour.

Have you also copied across the CSS from the styles.css file in the CodeSandbox example?

https://codesandbox.io/s/rutrh?module=/src/Example.tsx&file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Yup, so dumb but that was it, needed to specify a stroke color to the svg, thanks a lot!